# Cannot run Mex file

Tags: matlab, mex

In [this link](http://ivrl.epfl.ch/research/superpixels) there is MATLAB code with a mex file for an SLIC algorithm implementation.

I built it in MATLAB by writing `mex slicmex.c`.

I then ran `slicmex` but received this error:

```
Matlab has encountered an internal error and needs to be closed.
```

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: @Setsu I use Win7 operating system.

Comment: What compiler did Matlab use? `mex -setup` should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I ended up fixing the code. In the MEX file source change the line `int* dims;` to `const mwSize* dims;`. Should work now.

The problem is that the code wasn't 64-bit friendly and made some bad assumptions about the size of `int`.

---

I compiled the code they provided with Visual Studio 2013, and the resulting MEX file gave a fatal error when run from Matlab. Seems like they are dividing by zero somewhere. At this point you can either (1) contact the original authors and get them to look into it or (2) fix the code yourself. I've included the error message and stack trace below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Integer divide by zero detected at Fri Apr 17 15:28:50 2015
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : windows-1252
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Integer divide by zero

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00000000000c0000  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 00000000040260d0  RBP = 0000000004027260
  RSI = 0000000073de59e0  RDI = 0000000004026260

   R8 = 00000000097a81e0   R9 = 0000000000000201
  R10 = 00000000fe100000  R11 = 0000000004027260
  R12 = 000000000000127f  R13 = 00000000741ab430
  R14 = 0000000000000003  R15 = 0000000004027260

  RIP = 000007fef32c12fc  EFL = 00010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x000007fef32c12fc C:\Users\***\Projects\Visual Studio\Workspaces\Personal\CppTest\x64\Debug\slicmex.mexw64+00004860 mexFunction+00000700
[  1] 0x00000000fc5ef711 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00063249 mexRunMexFile+00000129
[  2] 0x00000000fc5ee1e2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00057826 inSwapMexfileReader+00000226
[  3] 0x00000000fc5ef294 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00062100 _constructor_lm_mexmaci64+00001620
[  4] 0x00000000045fbe4f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00048719 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000687
[  5] 0x00000000045fc77a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00051066 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000810
[  6] 0x0000000004775e04 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00744964 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00539764
[  7] 0x0000000004760782 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00657282 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00452082
[  8] 0x0000000004753f6f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00606063 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00400863
[  9] 0x000000000473cd43 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00511299 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00306099
[ 10] 0x000000000474644f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00549967 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00344767
[ 11] 0x0000000004749350 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00562000 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00356800
[ 12] 0x000000000476446f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00672879 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00467679
[ 13] 0x00000000047645b8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00673208 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00468008
[ 14] 0x0000000004754a2d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00608813 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00403613
[ 15] 0x000000000475192c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00596268 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00391068
[ 16] 0x00000000047611c9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00659913 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00454713
[ 17] 0x00000000045fc00e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00049166 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00001134
[ 18] 0x00000000045fc77a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00051066 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000810
[ 19] 0x000000000474cdfe C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00577022 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00371822
[ 20] 0x00000000047c68a7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01075367 inEachVisibleName+00016119
[ 21] 0x000000000474ab1a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00568090 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00362890
[ 22] 0x000000000476446f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00672879 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00467679
[ 23] 0x00000000047645b8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00673208 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00468008
[ 24] 0x0000000004754a2d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00608813 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00403613
[ 25] 0x000000000475192c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00596268 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00391068
[ 26] 0x00000000047611c9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00659913 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::GetID+00454713
[ 27] 0x00000000045fc00e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00049166 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00001134
[ 28] 0x00000000045fc77a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00051066 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000810
[ 29] 0x00000000047d4a0e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01133070 inValidateLoadedObject+00003486
[ 30] 0x00000000047dbd95 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01162645 inResetInterpreter+00005029
[ 31] 0x00000000047e0a05 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01182213 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::Copy+00010997
[ 32] 0x00000000047e09d2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01182162 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::Copy+00010946
[ 33] 0x00000000047e0997 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01182103 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::Copy+00010887
[ 34] 0x0000000004bce89c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+05302428 inMexPutVariable+00004204
[ 35] 0x0000000004bcebf6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+05303286 inMexPutVariable+00005062
[ 36] 0x0000000004bcf02e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+05304366 inMexPutVariable+00006142
[ 37] 0x0000000004bcf36c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+05305196 inMexPutVariable+00006972
[ 38] 0x0000000004ae0161 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+04325729 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000065
[ 39] 0x000000000413becd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00048845 mnDebugPrompt+00000109
[ 40] 0x000000000413cfaf C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00053167 mnParser+00000735
[ 41] 0x00000000fd0afae4   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00195300 mcrInstance::mnParser_on_interpreter_thread+00000036
[ 42] 0x00000000fd093af0   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00080624 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00029488
[ 43] 0x00000000fd093b50   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00080720 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00029584
[ 44] 0x00000000fab6e026   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00581670 UIW_IsUserMessage+00000086
[ 45] 0x00000000fab6e705   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00583429 UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+00000117
[ 46] 0x00000000fab6e789   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00583561 UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+00000249
[ 47] 0x00000000770a87fe                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00165886 GetMenuBarInfo+00000638
[ 48] 0x000000007708f5fb                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00062971 SystemParametersInfoW+00000235
[ 49] 0x0000000077094895                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00084117 IsProcessDPIAware+00000465
[ 50] 0x00000000772f04e5                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00328933 KiUserCallbackDispatcher+00000031
[ 51] 0x000000007709908a                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00102538 PeekMessageW+00000186
[ 52] 0x00000000770950fe                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00086270 GetKeyState+00000238
[ 53] 0x0000000077093a6f                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00080495 PeekMessageA+00000087
[ 54] 0x00000000fab1bd4b   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00245067 UIW_SetCurrentDialog+00000731
[ 55] 0x00000000fab6fbe2   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00588770 ws_FreeSystemFont+00000482
[ 56] 0x00000001000e2ed0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00995024 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00053488
[ 57] 0x00000001000e36a5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00997029 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00055493
[ 58] 0x00000001000e4330 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01000240 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::~PpeDispatchHook+00058704
[ 59] 0x00000001000ed4c6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01037510 sysq::removeProcessPendingEventsHook+00011030
[ 60] 0x00000001000ed7ca C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01038282 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00000138
[ 61] 0x00000000fd094b6d   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00084845 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00033709
[ 62] 0x00000000fd094e3b   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00085563 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00034427
[ 63] 0x00000000fd088b75   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00035701 mcrInstantiationError::operator=+00003221
[ 64] 0x00000000fd08bea2   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00048802 mcr_invoke_on_interpreter_thread+00001602
[ 65] 0x00000000fa7e6e5d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\MVMLocal.dll+00159325 mvm_server::inproc::LocalFactory::createMVM+00040653
[ 66] 0x00000000051dafaa   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00569258 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00001754
[ 67] 0x00000000051dd32a   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00578346 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00010842
[ 68] 0x00000000051dce85   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00577157 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00009653
[ 69] 0x0000000140004f79 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00020345
[ 70] 0x0000000140006a07 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00027143
[ 71] 0x00000000771959ed                   C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll+00088557 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000013
[ 72] 0x00000000772cba01                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00178689 RtlUserThreadStart+00000033


This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.

If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a lot of these mex-errors which makes MATLAB crushed.

I guess the mex function need some specific input which you don't give.

you know ,mex access input data with c/c++ pointers,so if there are wrong type or wrong number of input data,the pointer may out of range.

the most happened case is that mex need a single type input but you give a double type value ,which is default data type in MATLAB.

I recommend you to check the mex source code and figure out which kind of data type and number of input it need. In C/C++,float* corresponding to single in MATLAB ,and double* corresponding double in MATLAB.

that's all.  hope you can solve it.